# Using lodash with typescript and jspm

Tags: typescript, lodash, jspm

I am maybe doing something wrong but I cannot find what so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am Using typescript 2 + jspm. I think I tried all the possibilities inside the tsconfig using **typeRoots** and **types** (adding the version number in the name of the type). My current config is the following and it is not working whereas I think it should...

**package.json**

```
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "lodash": "npm:lodash@^4.17.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/lodash": "npm:@types/lodash@^4.14.45",
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4",
      "systemjs": "npm:systemjs@^0.19.41"
    }
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"typeRoots": [
  "jspm_packages/npm/@types"
]
```

Then compiler does not understand

```
import * as _ from "lodash"
```

I get

```
Cannot find module 'lodash'.
```

as suggested by the typescript doc https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html

Now if **I remove the import,** the funny thing is that vcode is able to go find the merge method definition (F12) if I write the following line of code

```
_.merge(a, b);
```

but compiler still complains that

```
Identifier '_' must be imported from a module
```

Any idea ? :)

Comment: You can import other modules without a problem or is it just lodash which is problematic?

Comment: I am using other modules without pb

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution but for now to avoid Typescript compiler complaining this is what I do

```
declare const _: any;
```

I just remove that line when I want completion for methods signature

Note that when I import lodash

```
 System.import('lodash').then((lodash) => {
     window._ = lodash;
 });
```